# Java Regex: find word that matches begin and end

Tags: java, regex

im new to Regular Expressions in general and I start to read more about them , so be gentle :-)

I want to find all words that begins with `my("` or `my('`. The word itself can contain underscores, characters, digits, basically any char. But it should end with `")` or `')`.

So I tried the following:

```
Pattern.compile("_(\"(.*)\")"); // for underscores first, instead of my
```

and

```
Pattern.compile("(my)(\"(.*)\")");
```

But this give me other things back as well, and I can't see why and where I making the thinking mistake...

Thanks

Comment: Is there a difference between the first and second `my("`? I assume you mean `my("` or `my('`, don't you?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I meant `my("` and `my('`

Comment: Would greatly help if you also include examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match `my("xxx")` and `my('xxx')` but not `my("xxx')` then try the following expression:

```
my\((?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*')\)
```

Here's a short breakdown of the expression:

- `my\(...\)`  means the match should start with `my(` and end with `)`
- `(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*')` means a sequence of characters surrounded by either double quotes or single quotes (therefore the character class means "any character not being a double quote" or "any character not being a single quote")

*Edit:*

The problem with the expression `(my)("(.*)")` is, that it is greedy and the match would start at `my("` but end on the last `")` due to the `.*` which matches anything. Thus it would match `my("xxx") your("yyy")` because `.*` matches `xxx") your("yyy`.

For more information on regular expressions see http://www.regular-expressions.info

Comment: From what I understood from the OP, you need to add the `^` and `$` anchors.

Comment: @npinti that might be the case, however, I interpreted "begin" and "end" being `my("` or `my('` and `")` or `')` in the OPs question.

Comment: Thanks, this one give me the best (complete) result back!

Answer (score 0):

In regular expressions, the brackets (`(` and `)`) are actually reserved characters so you will need to escape those. So this regex should do the trick: `_\\(\"(.*)\"\\)`. However, you also stated that you wanted to find words which *must begin* with `my(` and *must end* with `")`. So you will need to add anchors like so: `^my\\([\"'](.*)[\"']\\)$`. This should match any string which starts with `my("` or `my("'` and ends with `")` or `')`.

The `^` and `$` are anchors. The `^` will instruct the regex engine to start matching from the beginning of the string and the `$` will instruct the regex engine to stop matching at the end of the string. If you remove these anchors, the following would be considered as matches: `foo my('...') bar`, `my("...") bar`, etc.

This however will make no distinction and will match also strings like `my("...')` and `my('...")`.

Comment: You should write those regexes in the form of string literals like the OP did.  They're kind of ambiguous as they are.  For example, `\\(` could either be an escaped backslash followed by a grouping parenthesis, or just an escaped parenthesis.

Comment: @AlanMoore: With regards to `\\(`, that is actually both. In Java, to have a backslash you need to escape it. Since the OP is after matching brackets, which in regex terms need to be escaped by a backslash, which, due to the Java language, also needs to be escaped, hence you get `\\(`.

Comment: Of course; I'm just saying it's not *immediately* obvious unless you have prior experience using regexes in Java.  (And I mean anyone who reads this answer, not just the OP.)  Another potential source of confusion is the formatting provided by this site.  Newcomers who haven't yet learned to use it often add backslashes in order to prevent characters like `*` and `<` being treated as markup.  Then someone else comes along and adds code formatting, but they neglect to remove the extra backslashes.  You can head off a lot of confusion just by adding those two quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Use word boundry option,

```
\bmy\((["']).*?\1\)(?:\b|$)
```